# iPhone what declaration i need to inherit a class from 2 different classes

Tags: iphone, ios4

i have a class c. i have other two classes a and b. now i  want to use UITextField value from both classes a,  b in class c. So what i have to import?
Like what statement?

I know my question is bit childish but it will help for other users.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot inherit from two different classes in Objective-C.  You can however utilize protocols (similar to interfaces in other OO languages) to enforce similar behavior.  In most cases, if you re-consider your architecture, you can find a good clean way around this.

Comment: Hi,Can you explain how can i use protocol or give me link

Comment: Yes you r right but i want to access textField a from class A and textField b from class B , not methods. Your example explains inheritance of methods. i need to access  simple textField values in class c not methods.

Comment: Protocols can contain properties as well.